# Why is my CNN pre trained image classifier overfitting?

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, classification, data-science

I have just started with Computer Vision and in the current task i am classifying images in 4 categories.

Total number of image files=1043

I am using pretrained InceptionV3 and fine tuning it on my dataset.

This is what i have after the epoch:
Epoch 1/5
320/320 [==============================] - 1925s 6s/step - loss: 0.4318 - acc: 0.8526 - val_loss: 1.1202 - val_acc: 0.5557

Epoch 2/5
320/320 [==============================] - 1650s 5s/step - loss: 0.1807 - acc: 0.9446 - val_loss: 1.2694 - val_acc: 0.5436

Epoch 3/5
320/320 [==============================] - 1603s 5s/step - loss: 0.1236 - acc: 0.9572 - val_loss: 1.2597 - val_acc: 0.5546

Epoch 4/5
320/320 [==============================] - 1582s 5s/step - loss: 0.1057 - acc: 0.9671 - val_loss: 1.3845 - val_acc: 0.5457

Epoch 5/5
320/320 [==============================] - 1580s 5s/step - loss: 0.0982 - acc: 0.9700 - val_loss: 1.2771 - val_acc: 0.5572
That is a huge difference. Kindly help me to figure out why is my model not able to generalize as it is fitting quite well on the train data.

my code for reference:-

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input

CLASSES = 4

# setup model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])        

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['Category']= encoder.fit_transform(df['Category'])



from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

WIDTH = 299
HEIGHT = 299
BATCH_SIZE = 32


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)



validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


df['Category'] =df['Category'].astype(str)
#dfval['Category'] = dfval['Category'].astype(str)




from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df = shuffle(df)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dftrain,dftest = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dftrain,target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,class_mode='categorical', x_col='Path', y_col='Category')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dftest,target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH),batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,class_mode='categorical', x_col='Path', y_col='Category')



EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 32
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 320
VALIDATION_STEPS = 64

MODEL_FILE = 'filename.model'

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hard to say without being able to look at your data. What does it look like ?

Comment: Inception is a very deep neural network and works best on large amount of data, the number of images i.e. 1043 are very less for this type of network, hence it is overfitting. Try increasing the number of images

Comment: @JosephBudin images are scanned copies of documents.

Comment: @techytushar i am already augmenting the images.

Comment: @techytushar, I'm not sure it should overfit after 1 single epoch

Comment: @dataguy, what type of documents, are they really different intra-categories, inter-categories ? Are classes in the training and validation sets balanced the same way ? Have you tried without augmentation ?

Comment: So basically there are 4 different logos and each document has one on top of it and on the basis of that one easily gets to know what category it belongs to and that is what i want my model to learn. Havent really tried it without data augmentation.

Comment: @JosephBudin results without augmentation:- Epoch 1/5
320/320 [==============================] - 3497s 11s/step - loss: 0.3839 - acc: 0.8761 - val_loss: 1.4405 - val_acc: 0.4658

Comment: Already a lot better ! Can you isolate the logo (if it's always in the same corner of the document for instance, it'll help your network a lot). How did you divide the data into training/validation ?

Comment: @JosephBudin have updated the code and the validation accuracy as well. Kindly have a look. Model is still overfitting. :/

Comment: Have you tried freezing all the layers, except for the top one? Inception is really strong and it is expected to overfit with a small number of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `preprocess_input` in "all" your data, you will get terrible results.

Look at these:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input, 
    ...)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

Now, I notice you are using `rescale`. Since you imported the correct `preprocess_input` function from the inception code, I really think you should not be using this rescale. The `preprocess_input` function is supposed to do all the necessary preprocessing. (Not all models were trained with normalized inputs)

**But would rescale be a problem if you're applying it to both batasets?**

Well... if the `trainable=False` applied correctly to the `BatchNormalization` layers, this means that these layers have stored values for mean and variation which will only work well if the data is within the expected range.

Comment: Very right Daniel, i dont know how i missed that! have added the same. will let you know how the model performs. Thanks :)

Comment: surprisingly validation accuracy decreased from 48% to 12% when using "preprocess_input" in the validationgenerator

Comment: have updated the code and the validation accuracy as well. Kindly have a look. Model is still overfitting. :/

Comment: @dataguy I believe the problem is using a `rescale`. See details in the answer.

Comment: removed 'rescale' model is still overfitting.If i have to classify the document on the basis of  the logo on top of the same then what if i use object detection for classification?